# Theoretically question about update string items in tuples

Tags: python, string, tuples

Theoreticaclly question about tuples . 
If I have a tuple which construct from string:

```
tupl = ('Hello', 'World')
```

is that correct think if I want lowercase all the letters to use the same tuple or
Should I create a new tuple and copy the lowercase string of the current tuple?

```
tupl = [string.lower() for string in tupl]
```

or:

```
new_tuple = [string.lower() for string in tupl]
```

Comment: You're creating a list, not a tuple.

Comment: Both are essentially the same. You're creating a new list (not a tuple) in both cases. The difference is you're changing the object that `tupl` is associated with in the first.

Comment: Both strings and tuples are immutable, so this is going to be a new tuple (actually, list) in any case. The only difference is that it's bound to the old or to a new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, which means they can't be modified, only replaced.

In your first snippet, you're actually creating a list, but let's make it a tuple for the sake of example:

```
tupl = tuple(string.lower() for string in tupl)
```

If you run `id(tupl)` before and after this line, you'll see that the ID changes, since this line creates a new tuple, but assigns it to the same name, `tupl`. For example:

```
tupl = ('Hello', 'World')
old_id = id(tupl)
print(old_id)
tupl = tuple(string.lower() for string in tupl)
new_id = id(tupl)
print(new_id == old_id, new_id)
```

Example output:

```
140562289770120
False 140562192307208
```

The only difference in the second snippet is that it assigns the new object to a new name, and leaves the old name untouched.